# Monitoring java 8 processes to see actual memory use

Tags: java, linux, java-8, centos6

I would like to monitor java 8 processes on a Linux Centos system and be able to
see how much memory they are using.  I would prefer to use shell utilities as I wish to eventually feed the output into our central monitoring system

I am also baffled by the -Xmx options in java8 which seem to have no effect on the amount of memory used

Here is a script to get `ps` info on java programs

```
for jvm in `sudo -u services jps|awk '/.jar/ {print $1}'`; do ps up $jvm;done
```

output

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
services  1409  0.0 10.8 4672536 872440 ?      Tl   Jun03   3:53 /usr/java/lates
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
services  1574  0.0 11.4 4743036 925536 ?      Sl   Jun03   3:13 /usr/java/lates
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
services 19839  0.7 10.9 4735664 881420 ?      Sl   09:43   0:15 /usr/java/lates
```

Here are some settings from the programs

```
sudo -u services jps -lvm
1409 /usr/local/content-adapters/pmc-adapter/pmc-adapter.jar -Xmx1024m -Xms512m
1574 /usr/local/content-adapters/tools-adapter/tools-adapter.jar -Xmx512m
20685 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65 -Xms8m
19839 /usr/local/content-adapters/cas-adapter/cas-adapter.jar
```

some info on the server defaults

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 130023424                           {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 2063597568                          {product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

If I use jstat, I can't make the various "use" numbers add up to either the 4.5GiB
VSZ numbers above or the 800-900MiB RSS

My questions are

1. how do I relate the -Xmx and other settings to the amount of actual memory used?
2. how do I use jstat to show the amount of memory in use?
3. presumably the difference in VSZ and RSS is due to some kind of shared resources that all the java programs use.  How can I estimate or find this metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't pay much attention to virtual memory unless you set [vm.overcommit_memory = 2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting). Reserved-but-not-allocated address-space and memory-mapped files count towards that, so the metric is nearly useless since java reserves the entire heap in advance to have a continuous region available.

RSS is generally more interesting and assuming no paging happens should be somewhat larger than the currently allocated java heap, which in turn may be smaller than the maximum java heap (-Xmx)

Assuming the maximum heap capacity is not used and only small amounts of memory-mapping or direct byte buffer allocations happen and no paging happens the relation is something like this:

Non-garbage Objects < Java Heap used < Java Heap allocated < RSS < Java heap reserved (Xmx) < VSZ

Comment: In the examples I gave the "tools-adapter.jar" has a RSS of 903MB but a Xmx of 512M - like nearly double, so something about the stuff we are running must be going against your assumptions

Comment: In that case you could use `pmap` to look for mapped files and [java NMT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) to look for non-java-heap JVM stuff and heap dumps to look for direct byte buffers. Native libraries are also possible culprits, but those are hard to track.

Comment: @Vorsprung: perhaps your arguments have indeed no effect? Mind the semantic difference between `java -Xfoo -jar bar.jar` and `java -jar bar.jar -Xfoo`. Unfortunately, when using `jps` with the `-v` option, both are printed exactly the same…

Answer (score 0):

Additionally Java will use memory for metaspace. Also, depending on your code, java may use additional memory for byte buffer, direct memory.